# How to set Legend with Open Flash Chart 2 graphic using Open source Java API - JOFC?

Tags: graphics, seam, ofc

I have a [Seam 2.2](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/en-US/html/) app running under JBoss5.1. In this application I have successfully developed some Graphics using [Java Open Flash Chart](http://code.google.com/p/jofc2/), which is a Java API for [Open Flash Chart.](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/)

Now I would like to add a X and Y legend like [this one.](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/x-legend.php)

Well I have a graphic which is rendering properly and than I try to set X Label using:

...
chart.setXLegend(new Text("Legenda X"));

But than instead of showing the legend it corrupts something which causes the graphic to renders completely blank.

This is the generated JSon when the graphics renders correctly.

```
{"y_axis":{"min":388,"max":866,"steps":20},"title":{"text":"Gráfico de gasto mensal com Combustível"},"bg_colour":"#FFFFFF","is_decimal_separator_comma":0,"elements":[{"values":[{"tip":"R$:610.0\n05/2010","top":610},{"tip":"R$:488.0\n06/2010","top":488},{"tip":"R$:634.57\n07/2010","top":634.57},{"tip":"R$:766.0\n08/2010","top":766},{"tip":"R$:396.0\n09/2010","top":396},{"tip":"R$:610.0\n10/2010","top":610}],"type":"bar"}],"num_decimals":2,"is_fixed_num_decimals_forced":0,"x_axis":{"labels":{"labels":["05/2010","06/2010","07/2010","08/2010","09/2010","10/2010"]}},"is_thousand_separator_disabled":0}
```

I took a deeply look at it and turns out that whenever I try to add the x legend with the code fragment showed above the JSon is actually NOT generated by JOFC.

I could not find much useful documentation on JOFC on the web and the API itself is not very well documented, so I am completely lost on trying to add this simple x label, which should be the easiest part :( . Any Ideas on that.

An update:

Now I just have downloaded JOFC source code and will take a look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's an open issue on the JOFC page: http://code.google.com/p/jofc2/issues/detail?id=29

It suggests a workaround of calling the function like:

```
chart.setXLegend(new Text("Legenda X", Text.TEXT_ALIGN_CENTER))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try with Open Flash Grapix, it is easier to use, and just sets parameters on FlashVars.

[Open Flash Grapix](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openflashgrapix/)